# Filter functions results to undefined (useSelector)

Tags: reactjs, redux, filter, react-redux, find

So I have this line of code:

```
const { semesters, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.semester);
```

The `semesters` object looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "_id": "617aa8a3f2a712242c272d96",
    "acadYear": "A.Y. 2021- 2022, 2nd term",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "_id": "617aa91aa8f2aa2bc86422e9",
    "acadYear": "A.Y. 2025-2026, qweqwe",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to perform filter/find function in that array with this code.

```
const filtered = semesters.filter(sem => sem.isActive !== false)[0].acadYear;
```

or

```
const getFind = semesters.find(sem => sem.isActive !== false).acadYear;
```

Neither works for me and the error I'm getting is that both of the function is undefined. I've tried removing it and got no error. However, when I try to undo it and once it has already been loaded, then it will work. The problem is that when I go back to the page, the error will happen again. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the `useSelector` to pull values from Redux, ensure that the default value of `semesters` is an empty array not *undefined* (initializing the default values).

[Redux Docs: Initializing State](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)

Alternatively, you can handle this at execution using optional chaining operator:

```js
const firstNotActive = semesters?.find(sem => sem.isActive !== false)?.acadYear;
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because upon the very first render, the "semester" object is not yet available inside the redux store.

What you can do is use the optional chaining operator `?`, so that JavaScript checks if the object exists before attempting to run the chained function:

```
const filtered = semesters?.filter(sem => sem.isActive !== false)[0].acadYear;
```

This will return `undefined` and prevent the error. Once the store object is available, your `.filter` and `.find` functions will run accordingly.

There are other workarounds. I just find this one to be the one that better suits my needs in most cases.